# How to track down where an undeclared constant should have been defined in linux

Tags: c, linux

Trying to build an open source project ([systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd), not necesarilly relevant), I am stuck on the following error (also not directly relevant):

```
  CC       src/libsystemd/sd-rtnl/libsystemd_la-rtnl-types.lo
src/libsystemd/sd-rtnl/rtnl-types.c:278:10: error: 'IFLA_INET6_ADDR_GEN_MODE' undeclared here (not in a function)
         [IFLA_INET6_ADDR_GEN_MODE]      = { .type = NLA_U8 },
          ^
src/libsystemd/sd-rtnl/rtnl-types.c:278:9: error: array index in initializer not of integer type
         [IFLA_INET6_ADDR_GEN_MODE]      = { .type = NLA_U8 },
         ^
src/libsystemd/sd-rtnl/rtnl-types.c:278:9: error: (near initialization for 'rtnl_af_spec_inet6_types')
src/libsystemd/sd-rtnl/rtnl-types.c:278:9: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
src/libsystemd/sd-rtnl/rtnl-types.c:278:9: warning: (near initialization for 'rtnl_af_spec_inet6_types') [enabled by default]
```

My question is then:

**How do I figured out where `IFLA_INET6_ADDR_GEN_MODE` should have been defined / what header I'm missing**

My own ideas are:

1. Google the error message (no luck, ofc, otherwise I wouldn't be here..)
2. Search for it in all my files `sudo rgrep IFLA_INET6_ADDR_GEN_MODE /`
3. *Your ideas???*

A great answer would be the way you reason/study/learn to get to know where this constant is declared, enabling me and other readers to learn, rather than simply read a fact.

**Update (Build procedure):**

```
git clone git@github.com:systemd/systemd.git
cd systemd/
./autogen.sh
./configure CFLAGS='-g -O0 -ftrapv' --enable-compat-libs --enable-kdbus --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-gtk-doc --with-rootprefix= --with-rootlibdir=/lib --disable-gnutls
make
```

Comment: There should be a check in the configure script.  Look through the output of `configure` for relevant tests.

Comment: Can you paste the steps of how you built systemd. May be we can give it a try too?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I see nothing alarming in the output. What am I looking for? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2008558/configure.out

Answer (score 0):

I googgled the constant and got a pointer to http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network/322662. It seems to be declared in b/include/uapi/linux/if_link.h

Comment: Thats the Linux kernel sources

Comment: Searching for constants from `rtnl-types.c` with names similar to the missing one lead me to that file as well. `sudo find / -name 'if_link.h' -and -exec grep IFLA_INET6_ADDR_GEN_MODE {} \;` finds nothing so maybe my kernel is out of date? Maybe try with an release of systemd from before the referred patch?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after looking trough the problem, I realized my kernel header was not updated.

This variable was introduced between version 3.16 ~ 3.17 (not quite sure when but mine was 3.13 ).

To check out what you use

run the following:

```
% rpm -qf /usr/include/linux/if_link.h
```

or

```
uname -r
```

Also, this is a v219 new systemd feature which adds this dependency.

More info:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/NEWS#n291

You are trying to compile the origin/master HEAD, to test, try building v218.